GitHub Actions Build Successful, But Website Doesn't Reflect Code Changes (Deployment Issue)
I'm working on a project hosted on GitHub and using a build pipeline with GitHub Actions. While the build pipeline executes successfully, the changes I make to my index.html file aren't reflected on my live website. Here's a breakdown of what I'm experiencing:

Build Pipeline: My build pipeline seems to be working correctly. It fetches code from the repository, builds it (if necessary), and presumably completes all defined steps.
Code Changes: I've confirmed that the changes I make to my index.html file are committed and pushed to the GitHub repository successfully.
Website Not Updated: However, when I visit my live website, the changes to index.html are not reflected. It still displays the old version of the file.

I'd like to understand why the changes to index.html aren't reflected on my live website and how to ensure the build pipeline successfully deploys the updated code. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I've already tried clearing my browser cache and redeploying the website, but the changes still aren't reflected.
Environment:
Deployment Setup: I'm using Azure CDN and my custom domain for website deployment.
Build Pipeline: I'm using the following actions in my workflow YAML file:
actions/checkout@v4 (as suggested by the warning)
azure/login@v2 (as suggested by the warning)
Workflow Configuration: I copied the workflow configuration from the official Microsoft documentation: Link

I've added my Azure credentials as secrets in the GitHub repository, but I'm unsure if they're being used correctly by the azure/login@v2 action.
I'm following the Microsoft documentation for deploying a static site to GitHub Pages using Azure Storage Blobs, but the azure/login@v2 action seems unnecessary for this setup.

My frontend.yml file:
name: deploy_frontend

Deploys when push is made from the frontend folder
on:
push:
branches: [ main ]
paths:
- 'frontend/**'
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
- uses: azure/login@v2
with:
creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
- name: Upload to blob storage
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
        az storage blob upload-batch --account-name azureresumefaizan --auth-mode key -d '$web' -s frontend/
- name: Purge CDN endpoint
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
       az cdn endpoint purge --content-paths  "/*" --profile-name "azureresumefaizanshaikh" --name "azureresumefaizanshaikh" --resource-group "faizresume-rg"

Azure logout
- name: logout
  run: |
        az logout
  if: always()


Could you please share your yml file. are you using a normal html file for static web app or are you using any framework for static web app? for eg. react, vue, blazor, next, etc?

okay i will add my 'yml' content, and I am using a regular index.html @Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya

is it also possible for us to connect via github so you can see what I am struggling with @VivekVaibhavShandilya ?

If its possible to share your repo here

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Yeah let me share the link here:
https://github.com/faizP3RK/faizan_resume01


Website Doesn't Reflect Code Changes

Because you are not overwriting the changes to blob container.
you need to use --overwrite true in the command to  update changes.
this worked for me
name: deploy_frontend
# Deploys when push is made from the frontend folder

on:
    push:
        branches: 
            - main
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: azure login
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Upload to blob storage
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name blobstaticapp --account-key ${{vars.KEY}} -d '$web' -s frontend/ --overwrite true
    
    - name: Purge CDN endpoint
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: |
           az cdn endpoint purge --content-paths  "/*" --profile-name "blobcdn" --name "blobstaticcdn" --resource-group "<resourcegroupname>"
  # Azure logout
    - name: logout
      run: |
            az logout
      if: always()

OUTPUT:
I used your git repo and cloned.
Azure CDN
Before :

GitHub Build and Deployment :

After :

Original static website url :


hey @VivekVaibhavShandilya it possible for you to help me over zoom? I am having some difficulty if we can connect over
LinkedIn

Also when my counter stopped working, I used the code that had and changed it to my own variable and resource names, but my visitor counter doesn't work. Could you help with that and check out my repo @VivekVaibhavShandilya

@FaizanShaikh are you getting any error on code or just the visitor counter is not updated in database?

hey not getting any errors, just the visitor counter is not showing up on my live website, here is my actually website the counter doesn't seem to be there I don't know if pushing it made that happen.

@FaizanShaikh You are using Function for adding the counter, you are using http trigger for that you need to trigger the function by going to api route.

@FaizanShaikh please check you counter now. You will have to trigger the function using this url https://www.faiznmo.live/api/GetResumeCounter.

hey @VivekVaibhavShandilya I tried that link, it doesn't work, my CosmosDB data is also not updating every time i refresh my website page. I also tried the link you gave me on multiple browsers and it doesn't update the data for visit counter. I am not sure what the issue is, if you could help me troubleshoot this, this problem happened after I was able to do the -overwrite true thing for my frontend as you gave me, not sure what the problem is but I am going to finish the backend.yml file and see if it works but if you can help me find a solution. Thank you for your help appreciate it lot.

Also @VivekVaibhavShandilya I successfully was able to push both the backend.yml and fronend.yml, my only problem is that the function is not working, I even looked at using inspect elements on my live website to see any errors on the terminal regarding it but nothing, I think the fix might be on Azure Portal but you could look at my repo and lmk a fix it would mean a lot thank you so much.

@FaizanShaikh was counter working before using --overwrite?

yeah @VivekVaibhavShandilya it was working before, I updated some stuff and GitHub Repo if you want to check it out and clone it and see what the issue might be with the counter. I really appreciate your help thank you.

@FaizanShaikh You need to provide cosmos DB name and Container name directly in the code. do not fetch values from local.settings file. In azure local.settings file does not work. in storage static website there is no option to define environment variables

Hey @VivekVaibhavShandilya I updated the code to do what you said but it still does not work, the counter still doesn't work or update in my AzureCosmosDB. I tried to even add the Key value directly into the code and build it using dotnet but still does not work. I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

@FaizanShaikh Blob static website does not support server side scripting. image. You need to deploy a static website instead of blob storage static website.

okay @VivekVaibhavShandilya so I think I know what I can try doing, I was thinking about doing Azure Static Web Apps to host the backend instead since it will allow for that, but i need help on how I would migrate what I have done so far to that, not sure how to get started on that. if you could guide me.

@FaizanShaikh raise a new question for static Web apps

okay let me do that @VivekVaibhavShandilya

Hey Link I made a new post regarding this if you can check it out and help me with that @VivekVaibhavShandilya sorry for taking a long time, had exams week.

Hi @FaizanShaikh You need to update your new question with more details to be opened. as it closed.
